# The flashing button (very basic)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I created a very (and I can't stress that enough) simple program since I am just starting out learning WPF.

It's so simple, in fact, that I can write it all here:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="825">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="125" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="0,10,200,10">
        <Button Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="50" Width="100" Content="Tester" Background="Coral">

        </Button>    
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

But this program has a problem. The button flashes.

When I load up the program, the button is a coral colour (as expected). If I mouse over it, it turns back to the original colour (I guess that colour comes from the control that holds it? As you can see, I only specify one colour for the button.)

The issue comes when I click the button (left mouse). When I do this, the button transitions from one colour (coral) to the other (alice blue) over a period of about a second. It goes back and forth over and over. If I mouse over it in this state, it returns to the mouse over colour as it would do normally, but then when I take my mouse away from it, it starts flashing again.

To be clear: this is not about the change of colour on mouseover. I'm fine with that. After I click the button, said button transitions between two colours over and over again. The colours are coral and the mouse over colour, which of course I have not specified.

I am at a loss here. I've not told it to do this (have I?) I haven't clicked anything in the properties or written any code behind. The XAML is ALL that I have done.

Why on earth does the button flash?

**Edit** here are some [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gP2E.jpg) which show the entire thing. All code (there isn't any). The XAML, the app.xaml.cs, everything.

**Edit 2** another image with all the [button properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLpZ5.jpg). I didn't change any, so far as I know.

Comment: Can't reproduce what you described with the code you have provided.

Comment: @R.Rusev He's talking about the ordinary WPF button mouseover background color change. In Win7, at any rate, I see exactly what he does. "Flash" isn't at all the word I'd use to describe it, but he says the effect is that the color is different when the mouse is over the button.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's not exactly what I'm saying. I'm saying that, when I click on the button, then move my mouse away from it, it enters a cycle where it goes from coral, to the default colour, then back to coral, then back to the default colour and so on indefinitely.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner Oh, OK. Sorry. I hadn't tried clicking the test button I copied from your XAML. But now that I click it, I am seeing exactly what you see: It cycles between blue and coral as long as it retains keyboard focus. When I tab out or click another control, the cycling stops. In fact if I take out the `Background` attribute, I see the same again, but it cycles between the default inert gray gradient, to the "active" blue gradient, which is a much more subtle difference but still noticeable.

Comment: Did you try to define a custom template as suggested?

Comment: @mm8 I did do that, and now I have a button that doesn't do anything. I mean I was fine with the mouse over and all the things like that. The weird constant colour changing after a click was the issue. Seems rather like this is the nuclear option to solve it.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner what you want to do is create a copy of the original template, and just alter that.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the default styles in windows.

A normal button (on windows 7) transitions from a two tone grey to a two tone blue, it's triggered by the default control template.

You can edit the control template and set the style on the button..

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="825">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="125" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="0,10,200,10">
            <Button Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="50" Width="100" Content="Tester" Background="Coral" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can now see where the other colours are coming from

Removing the attributes `RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}"` from `<Themes:ButtonChrome` and the                   `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` disables this behaviour

Comment: But custom template is not specified in XAML, how could windows default template be fixed then?

Comment: @foobar, There's always a template. Either a custom one is specified such as in mm8's answer, or it uses the one in the style. Which again can be custom as in my example (although it's a copy of the default it's still custom).  You can't "fix" the windows default template/style, but you can edit a copy and do whatever you like with it.

Comment: I'm rather a WPF newbie and so I'm not sure quite *where* to put your XAML.

I tried the top of my XAML, outside of the 'Window' tag. When I do this, I get 5 errors, the first of which is 'The type 'Style' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.'

@JamesBarrass Then I tried inside the Window tag, above the grid tag. If I do this, I get 6 errors, the first of which is :'The type 'Themes:ButtonChrome' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been bu

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner updated to include the missing bits. VisualStudio should do this for you if you `Right Click` -> `Edit Template` -> `Edit a Copy...` on the button. I think this depends on your VS version

Comment: Thank you for your continued help, and now it does look better, bar one error: 'the type Themes:ButtonChrome was not found.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner You might need to add a reference. The **Themes** namespace should be declared in the window (see example) and the assembly in that line will need to be in your references

Answer (score 2):

The "flashing" you are experiencing probably comes from the default template of the `Button`. You can override it to make your `Button` look like a plain rectangle without any kind of effects:

```
<Button Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="50" Width="100" Content="Tester" Background="Coral">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```